# Отправка почты с хостинга

Tags: yii2

Здравствуйте!!!
Возникает периодически проблема с отправкой почты. Не могу понять логику происходящего.
Почта с хостинга, то отправляется, то не отправляется. На локалке все нормально: отправляется постоянно.
Часть кода модели:

```
public $toEmail = ['agavrilenko@belstekloprom.com', 'bspgomel@gmail.com']; //на какую почту будут приходить письма

public function sendEmail()
    {
        if ($this->validate()) {
            Yii::$app->mailer->compose()
                ->setTo($this->toEmail)
                ->setFrom([$this->email => $this->name])
                ->setReplyTo([$this->email => $this->name])
                ->setSubject($this->subject)
                ->setTextBody($this->body)
                ->send();

            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }

    }
```

Часть кода контроллера:

```
$model = new ContactForm();
        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
            if ($model->sendEmail()){
                Yii::$app->session->setFlash('success', 'Спасибо за Ваше письмо. Мы постараемся как можно быстрее Вам ответить!');
                return $this->refresh();
            } else {
                Yii::$app->session->setFlash('error', 'Внимание! Ваше письмо по каким-то причинам не отправлено!!!');
            }
        }
```

Часть кода настройки конфига:

```
'mailer' => [
            'class' => 'yii\swiftmailer\Mailer',
            'useFileTransport' => false,
            /*'transport' => [
                'class' => 'Swift_SmtpTransport',
                'host' => 'smtp.mail.ru',
                'username' => 'goric0312@mail.ru',
                'password' => '*********************',
                'port' => '465',
                'encryption' => 'ssl',
            ],*/
        ],
```

Обязательно ли в main.php - конфигурационном файле указывать метод 'transport'?
Если я его включаю, то почта вообще не приходит и выдает ошибку.
А без него, то приходит, то не приходит почта. Не пойму.
Сообщение об отправленной почте высвечивается, а сама почта, то приходит, то не приходит.
Спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

На хостинге нужно настраивать поле `transport`. Если почта не приходит - смотрите файлы логов (папка `runtime/logs`), в них должна быть написана ошибка.